# Save dynamic table rows in MongoDB using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I've written some JavaScript to dynamically add rows to a `<table>`. How can I save data from the dynamically generated rows to my MongoDB database?
I have added php code to save table in mongodb.
there is a variable nextName which increments the name variable to help generate variables.
Here is my HTML and JavaScript:

```
nextName=2;
    function myCreateFunction(tableid) {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableid);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
      var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
          case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            newcell.childNodes[0].name = "name' + nextName + '";
            break;
          case "checkbox":
            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
            break;
          case "select-one":
            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            break;
        }nextName++;
      }

    }

    function myDeleteFunction(tableID) {
      try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
          var row = table.rows[i];
          var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
          if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if (rowCount <= 1) {
              alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
              break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
    <table border="1" id="myTable">

      <tr>
        <th>select</th>
        <th>Degree</th>
        <th>H.R.A.</th>
        <th>College/University</th>
        <th>Divn.</th>
        <th>%age/CGPA</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
        <td>
          <select id="ddeg" name="ddeg">
            <option value="degg1">P.H.D.</option>
            <option value="degg2">M.C.A.</option>
            <option value="degg3">B.Sc</option>
            <option value="degg4">B.E.</option>
            <option value="degg5">12th</option>
            <option value="degg6">10th</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="hran" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="college" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="divn" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cg" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="remark" /></td>
      </tr>
      
    </table>

    <br>
    <button onclick="myCreateFunction('myTable')">Add row</button>
    <button onclick="myDeleteFunction('myTable')">Delete row</button>
    <br>




<?php

session_start();
 $m = new MongoClient();
 $db=$m->form;
 $col=$db->mycol;

 $url=$target_file;
 $arr=array();
 for($x=2;$x<=nextName;$x++)
 {
     $arr[$x]=$_POST["name' + $x + '"];
 }
 $y=0;
 $new = array(

                         foreach($arr as $value)
                         {
                             "tab' + $y + '"=>$value;
                         $y++;
                         }

                        );

                 $col->insert($new);

?>
```

Comment: There isn't an ounce of PHP there...plus the code formatting is making my eyes bleed

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and where you got stuck. Start by writing some PHP code to process the submitted form.

Comment: I have added the php code in the end.
The variable nextName is used just an idea by me to generate dynamic variables in the array to save table contents in mongodb.